# Proving ${\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}} E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}-E[Y_1]\right|\right]=0$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I have the following problem from my book about Markov processes:

> Let $\{Y_n:n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of mutually independent,
>   identically distributed random variables satisfying $E[Y_1]<\infty$.
>   Set $X_n=\sum_{m=1}^n Y_m$ for $n\geq 1$. The Weak Law of Large
>   Numbers says that
>
> $$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n}-E[Y_1]\right|\geq
>  \epsilon\right)\rightarrow 0\;\;\;\text{for all } \epsilon>0.$$
>
> In fact,
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}-E[Y_1]\right|\right]=0,\;\;\;\;\;\;(1.3.3)$$
>
> from which the above follows as an application of Markov's inequality.
>   Here are steps which lead to (1.3.3).
>
> (a) First reduce to the case when $E[Y_1]=0$. Next, asume that
>   $E[Y_1^2]<\infty$, and show that
>
> $$E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]^2 \leq
>  E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|^2\right]=\frac{E[Y_1^2]}{n}.$$
>
> Hence the result is proved when $Y_1$ has a finite second moment.
>
> (b) Given $R>0$, set $Y_n^{(R)}=Y_n\textbf{1}_{[0,R)}(|Y_n|)-E[Y_n,
>  |Y_n|<R]$ and $X_n^{(R)}=\sum_{m=1}^nY_m^{(R)}$ Note that, for any
>    $R>0,$
>
> $$E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]\leq
>  E\left[\left|\frac{X_n^{(R)}}{n}\right|\right]+E\left[\left|\frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n}\right|\right]\leq\sqrt{E\left[\left(\frac{X_n^{(R)}}{n}\right)^2\right]}+2E[|Y_1|,
>  |Y_1|\geq R]\leq \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}+2E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R],$$
>
> and use this, together with the Monotone Convergence Theorem, to
>   complete the proof of $(1.3.3)$

I have succesfully solved part (a) but I'm stuck now in part (b). **My question therefore is: how do I solve part (b)?**

Comment: What does $E[Y_n, |Y_n|<R]$ mean?

Comment: I get to the following inequality: $E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]-\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}-2E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R] \leq E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}-E[Y_1]\right|\right]\leq E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]+\frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}+2E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R]$, but now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Jack accroding to the book's author the notation $E[X,A]$ means: "The expected value of $X$ on the event $A$".

Comment: @Jack "An Introduction to Markov Processess" by Daniel W. Stroock, http://148.206.53.84/tesiuami/S_pdfs/108944%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Markov%20Processes.pdf

Comment: See the book link and check page 179 where author presents the notation list.

Comment: @Jack thank you for your help! If you could post your comment as answer and elaborate a little bit more I'd be able to accept it :) Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have had the long inequality in the hint of (b):

> $$
> E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]\leq \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}
> +2E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R],$$

take the $\limsup$ on both sides gives
$$
\limsup_n E\left[\left|\frac{X_n}{n}\right|\right]\leq 2E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R]\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, (1) is true for all $R>0$, and
$$
E[|Y_1|, |Y_1|\geq R]\to 0,\quad\hbox{as }R\to\infty
$$
by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: I think my main problem was in applying the M.C.T because it's a bit unfamiliar to me.